# How to identify subjects and verbs in a sentence?

Tags: passive-voice, be

"Just as expert carpenters must be thoroughly acquainted with the tools of their craft and artists must have expert knowledge of colors, so good writers must have a thorough understanding of the basic material with which they work: words."

The sentence above is from a book.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking. The summary of your question doesn't seem to match the body. Are you only asking if the passage you gave is in the passive voice? What is it about the passage that you can't make sense of? Is it the overall *Just as X, so must Y* construction?

Comment: I guess I'm asking multiple questions here. First is how do you know which subject goes with which verb when a sentence is long and complex?  Is , the part, must be thoroughly acquainted, passive ? and how to understand passive sentences?

Comment: Is it possible to edit this question to only ask a single question—and then post new questions for the rest? It would make proving answers simpler. If you want to keep this one as identifying subjects and verbs, I could answer that piece here.

Comment: I fixed the title.

Comment: Please specify which subject exactly *you* think goes with exactly which verb, why exactly you think that, and why exactly you think that what you think is wrong. "I have identified X, but I think it could be Y because of reason Z" is an actual problem we can help you with. "I have not identified anything at all" is not a problem, and is also not true. Certainly you have *some* idea of what the sentence means. So tell us just that in your own words. Thanks.

Comment: I was seconds away from posting a detailed answer to this question for you.  You can analyze it as having three clauses. "Just as (**carpenters must be** and **artists must have**), **writers must have.**" Three subjects and three verbs. The *essential* meaning of the sentence is **Good writers must have a thorough understanding of words.**

Answer (score 0):

Look through the sentence for all people, places, and things. Any of these that are meaningfully associated with an action word are regarded as subjects.

This particular complex sentence provides three subjects: *carpenters*, *artists*, and *writers*. Each of these subjects is paired with a verb: *to be*, *to have*, and *to have*.

The extra nouns (e.g. "tools") are not subjects of the sentence.

Comment: Ok, can you help me with the first part containing,must be thoroughly acquainted, is this a passive verb or an adjective?

Comment: It's an adjective. It can't be passive because there's no agent who is accustoming the carpenters to the tools of their craft; instead, they are in a state of being accustomed to (used to, familiar with) to their tools. You can't add an agent _by_-phrase to these sentence. By the way, there's a pied-piped relative clause in the last part: _with which they work_, and it has a subject _they_. The subject is the noun phrase that agrees with (and usually precedes) the first auxiliary verb in the clause.